# Is there a continuous $f:\mathbb C^2→\mathbb C$ such that $f(x, y)^2 = x^2 + y^2$?

Tags: complex-numbers, functional-equations

This would be a sort of complex-valued analogue of the Euclidean metric.

I would have thought that we could prove there isn't such an $f$ by using the fact that there isn't a continuous right inverse to $z\mapsto z^2$. But I can't find a proof or an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mindlack's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3405574/1149) is good, but I found a nicer answer [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/math/comments/djpo4h/simple_questions_october_18_2019/f4uknal/?st=k2393rt0&sh=0bfecc97) in the meantime.

Suppose such an $f$ exists, and for $z\in\mathbb C$ let $x = \frac{z+1}{2}$ and $y=\frac{z-1}{2i}$. Then

$$f\left(\frac{z+1}{2},\frac{z-1}{2i}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{z+1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{z-1}{2i}\right)^2=\frac{z^2+2z+1}4-\frac{z^2-2z+1}4=z$$

so $z\mapsto f\left(\frac{z+1}{2},\frac{z-1}{2i}\right)$ is a continuous right inverse to $z\mapsto z^2$, contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

We have $f(x,1)^2=x^2+1$, and $f(\cdot,1)$ is continuous.

Note that since there is a holomorphic square root in a neighborhood of any complex number but zero, $f(\cdot,1)$ is continuous and holomorphic everywhere except at $i$ and $-i$. By Moreira, $f(\cdot,1)$ is holomorphic.

It vanishes at $x=i$, so $f(\cdot,1)^2=X^2+1$ should vanish with order $2$ at least at $i$. This is not the case, hence a contradiction and $f$ does not exist.

Comment: How do you know that $f(\cdot,1)$ is entire ?

Comment: @C.Brendel its $f^2 = x^2 + 1$, not $f$

Comment: right, overlooked that! Thanks!